Move Everything in a Directory Up One Level
Let's say I have this:
myfiles/stuff/things/whatever.txt

I want to move everything in the "things" directory to the "stuff" directory without listing each file one at a time. In my example, I have 1 file, but in real life, I have 1000 files.
Any suggestions?

superuser is the site for questions like this

I'm assuming there is no restriction for you to use the linux terminal here.
If you are in the myfiles/stuff/things directory then do
mv * ..

or if you want to move in general
mv myfiles/stuff/things/* myfiles/stuff/


Please don't answer off-topic questions. Thanks.

But the answer is correct

@MohamedRaza and your point is?

moving file from one place to another is absolute correct
